# Check if string has sequential characters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to validate a string to find out if it contains some sequential characters of 3 or more.

Example:

```
"11abcd$4567" => ['abcd', '4567']
```

Tried to do this by a regular expression but it looks much longer to code:

```
(?!abc|bcd|cde|.....)
```

Is there an easy way to check the sequential characters either by a regex or plain ruby ?

Comment: use include method. '11abcd$4567'.include? 'abc'.  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: Sequence can be any string not just 'abc'. It can be 'defgh' etc

Comment: Umm select should work like. a = 'abc'.chars; a.select{ |b| str.include?(b)}

Comment: What sequences do you want to detect, just a..z and 0..9?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, a..z and 0..9 e.g 2345, defg... etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regexp is not appropriate here. They are not flexible enough that one could construct a general case; and Unicode is vast, and constructing a regexp that responds to any ascending sequence of characters would take listing each of the tens or hundreds of thousands of cases. It could be done programatically, but it would take time, and would be pretty costly, memory-wise.

```
def find_streaks(string, min_length=3)
  string                                 # "xabcy"
    .each_char                           # ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'y']
    .chunk_while { |a, b| a.succ == b }  # [['x'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['y']]
    .select { |c| c.size >= min_length } # [['a', 'b', 'c']]
    .map(&:join)                         # ['abc']
end
```

I guess this might work as a polyfill... Give it a try?

```
                                         # skip this thing on Ruby 2.3+, unneeded
unless Enumerable.instance_methods.include?(:chunk_while)
  module Enumerable
    def chunk_while                      # let's polyfill!
      streak = nil                       # twofold purpose: init `streak` outside
                                         # the block, and `nil` as flag to spot
                                         # the first element.

      Enumerator.new do |y|              # `chunk_while` returns an `Enumerator`.
        each do |element|                # go through all the elements.
          if streak                      # except on first element:
            if yield streak[-1], element # give the previous element and current
                                         # one to the comparator block.
                                         # `streak` will always have an element. 
              streak << element          # if the two elements are "similar",
                                         # add this one to the streak;
            else                         # otherwise
              y.yield streak             # output the current streak and
              streak = [element]         # start a new one with the current element.
            end
          else                           # for the first element, nothing to compare
            streak = [element]           # so just start the streak.
          end
        end
        y.yield streak if streak         # output the last streak;
                                         # but if `streak` is `nil`, there were
                                         # no elements, so no output.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Well, derp. Here I go writing all this by hand... when it could have been as easy as this:

```
unless Enumerable.instance_methods.include?(:chunk_while)
  module Enumerable
    def chunk_while
      slice_when { |a, b| !yield a, b }
    end
  end
end
```

Yup, `chunk_while` is just the opposite of `slice_when`. Could have even substituted it in the original code, as `.slice_when { |a, b| a.succ != b }`. Sometimes I'm slow.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `chunk_while' for #<Enumerator: "xabcy":each_char>

Comment: Your Ruby is old. `chunk_while` was added in 2.3.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: Any alternate of `chunk_while` that would work with Ruby 2.2.3 ?

Comment: _"Regexp is not appropriate here"_ – could you elaborate? Would a regexp be slow or hard to construct?

Comment: `string.each_char.slice_when { |a, b| a.succ != b }.select { |c| c.size >= 3 }.map(&:join)` works for me.

Comment: Amadan and @Stefan, except for some minor pre-processing, I found a way to use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat solution I came up with. So I tried to take take advantage of Ruby's memory referencing in an odd way. Pseudocode:

1. Loop through the string.
2. Convert the character into an `ascii` through the `ord` method
3. if `mem` variable is empty or the last character of `mem`, converted to ascii, is equal to the ascii of the current character minus 1, store it to mem
4. If `mem` variable has `3` sequential characters, store it in `arr` variable.

NOTE: here's where it gets tricky, you might see that it might be a problem because your condition clearly states "get 3 or more sequential characters". The "<<" when used, `mutates` the `string` object that we pushed from the `arr` variable. As long as the `mem` variable is not `reinitialized` by our assignment operator, =, it will keep on mutating the the string object you push into the array.

```
str = "11abcdefgh$4567"

arr = []
mem = ""

str.each_char do |s|
  if mem.empty? || (mem[-1].ord == s.ord - 1)
    mem << s
  else
    mem = ""
  end

  if mem.size == 3
    arr << mem
  end
end
puts arr
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the title and first sentence of the question state that the task is to determine if a given string contains at least three consecutive characters that are in (I assume ASCII) order (e.g., `"def"` and `"!"#'`), even thought that seems to  conflict with the example. One quick way of answering that question (which may not be as efficient as other approaches) is as follows.

**Code**

```
def at_least_so_many_consecutive(str, min_run_size)
  (32.chr..126.chr).each_cons(min_run_size).
                    map(&:join).
                    any? { |s| str.include?(s) }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "xabc$fghrtuvwx3!"
at_least_so_many_consecutive(str, 3)
  #=> true
at_least_so_many_consecutive(str, 5)
  #=> true
at_least_so_many_consecutive(str, 6)
  #=> false
```

Note:

```
(32.chr..126.chr).each_cons(min_run_size).map(&:join)
  #=> [" !\"", "!\"#", "\"\#$", "\#$%", "$%&", "%&'", "&'(", "'()", "()*",
  #    ")*+", "*+,", "+,-", ",-.", "-./", "./0", "/01", "012", "123", "234",
  #   ...
  #    "QRS", "RST", "STU", "TUV", "UVW", "VWX", "WXY", "XYZ", "YZ[", "Z[\\", 
  #    "[\\]", "\\]^", "]^_", "^_`", "_`a", "`ab", "abc", "bcd", "cde", "def",
  #   ...
  #    "opq", "pqr", "qrs", "rst", "stu", "tuv", "uvw", "vwx", "wxy", "xyz",
  #    "yz{", "z{|", "{|}", "|}~"]
```

**Another interpretation**

My initial interpretion was that all substrings of three or more characters that met the criterion were to be returned (even though this was also inconsistent with the example). Nevertheless, I'll leave my solution (below) for that problem.

**Code**

```
def runs_of_min_size_or_more(str, min_run_size)
  arr = str.chars
  (arr.size-min_run_size+1).times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
    run = arr.lazy.slice_when { |x,y| y != x.next }.first
    a << run.join if run.size >= min_run_size
    arr.shift
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "xabc$fghrtuvwx3!"

runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 1
  #=> ["x", "abc", "bc", "c", "$", "fgh", "gh", "h", "r", "tuvwx",
  #    "uvwx", "vwx", "wx", "x", "3"] 
runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 2
  #=> ["abc", "bc", "fgh", "gh", "tuvwx", "uvwx", "vwx", "wx"] 
runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 3
  # => ["abc", "fgh", "tuvwx", "uvwx", "vwx"]
runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 4
  #=> ["tuvwx", "uvwx"] 
runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 5
  #=> ["tuvwx"]
runs_of_min_size_or_more str, 6
  #=> []
```

**Explanation**

See [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), which first made its appearance in Ruby v2.2. I've made `slice_when` a lazy enumerator so that by adding `.first` at the end of its block the slicing will terminate after the first slice has been obtained.

The easiest way of showing what is going on here is to insert some `puts` statements in the code and then execute it. I've also broken

```
run = arr.lazy.slice_when { |x,y| y != x.next }.first
```

into

```
slice = arr.lazy.slice_when { |x,y| y != x.next }
run = slice.first
```

but since `slice` is an enumerator I've printed `slice.to_a` which is an array of the elements the enumerator will generate.

```
def runs_of_min_size_or_more(str, min_run_size)
  arr = str.chars
  rv = (arr.size-min_run_size+1).times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
    puts "arr=#{arr}"
    puts "  a=#{a}"
    slice = arr.lazy.slice_when { |x,y| y != x.next }
    puts "  slice.to_a=#{slice.to_a}"
    run = slice.first
    puts "  run=#{run}"
    puts "  reject '#{run.join}' because run.size=#{run.size} < #{min_run_size}" \
      if run.size  < min_run_size
    a << run.join if run.size >= min_run_size
    puts "  run.join=#{run.join}" if run.size >= min_run_size 
    arr.shift
  end
  puts "arr=#{arr}"
  rv
end
```

```
runs_of_min_size_or_more "xabc$rtuv3!", 2

arr=["x", "a", "b", "c", "$", "r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=[]
  slice.to_a=[["x"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["$"], ["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["x"]
  reject 'x' because run.size=1 < 2
arr=["a", "b", "c", "$", "r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=[]
  slice.to_a=[["a", "b", "c"], ["$"], ["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["a", "b", "c"]
  run.join=abc
arr=["b", "c", "$", "r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc"]
  slice.to_a=[["b", "c"], ["$"], ["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["b", "c"]
  run.join=bc
arr=["c", "$", "r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc"]
  slice.to_a=[["c"], ["$"], ["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["c"]
  reject 'c' because run.size=1 < 2
```

```
arr=["$", "r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc"]
  slice.to_a=[["$"], ["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["$"]
  reject '$' because run.size=1 < 2
arr=["r", "t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc"]
  slice.to_a=[["r"], ["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["r"]
  reject 'r' because run.size=1 < 2
arr=["t", "u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc"]
  slice.to_a=[["t", "u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["t", "u", "v"]
  run.join=tuv
arr=["u", "v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc", "tuv"]
  slice.to_a=[["u", "v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["u", "v"]
  run.join=uv
arr=["v", "3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc", "tuv", "uv"]
  slice.to_a=[["v"], ["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["v"]
  reject 'v' because run.size=1 < 2
arr=["3", "!"]
  a=["abc", "bc", "tuv", "uv"]
  slice.to_a=[["3"], ["!"]]
  run=["3"]
  reject '3' because run.size=1 < 2
arr=["!"]
  #=> ["abc", "bc", "tuv", "uv"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been pondering whether this could be done with a regular expression. I've found a way, but it does require some pre-processing. (It also only works for short strings, as pointed out in the comments. Oh, well some might find the approach of interest.)

**Code**

```
def runs_of_min_size_or_more(str, min_run_size)
  arr = []
  str.each_char.with_index.map { |c,i| (c.ord-i).chr }.
      join.
      scan(/(.)(?=(\1{#{min_run_size-1},}))/) do |m|
        offset = Regexp.last_match.begin(0)-1
        arr << m.join.gsub(/./) do |c|
          offset += 1
        (c.ord + offset).chr
        end
      end
  arr
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "xabc$fghrtuvwx3!"
min_run_size = 3
runs_of_min_size_or_more(str, min_run_size)
  #=> ["abc", "fgh", "tuvwx", "uvwx", "vwx"]
```

**Explanation**

Note that the return value of [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is not used. `scan`'s only function is to build the array `arr`.

For the values of `str` and `min_run_size` given in the example, the steps are as follows. First, the pre-processing step.

````
arr = []
a = str.each_char.with_index.map { |c,i| (c.ord-i).chr }
  #=> ["x", "`", "`", "`", " ", "a", "a", "a", "j", "k", "k", "k", "k", "k",
  #    "%", "\x12"] 
b = a.join
  #=> "x``` aaajkkkkk%\x12"
````

The regex that is `scan`'s argument is the following when defined in *free-spacing mode*:

````
r = /
    (.)                 # match any character in capture group 1
    (?=                      # begin a positive lookahead
      (                      # begin capture group 2
        \1                   # match the content of capture group 1...
        {#{min_run_size-1},} # at least min_run_size-1 times 
      )                      # end capture group 2
    )                        # end positive lookahead
    /x                       # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
      (.)                    # match any character in capture group 1
      (?=                    # begin a positive lookahead
        (                    # begin capture group 2
          \1                 # match the content of capture group 1...
          {2,}               # at least min_run_size-1 times 
        )                    # end capture group 2
      )                   # end positive lookahead
    /x 

b.scan(r) do |m|
  offset = Regexp.last_match.begin(0)-1
  arr << m.join.gsub(/./) do |c|
           offset += 1
           (c.ord + offset).chr
         end
end
  #=> "x``` aaajkkkkk%\x12"
arr
  #=> ["abc", "fgh", "tuvwx", "uvwx", "vwx"]
````

Comment: `runs_of_min_size_or_more("0" * 50, 3)` will kill it. `runs_of_min_size_or_more("123456", 3)` finds four runs. But those are tiny and solvable things; my primary problem with this is that the amount of pre- and post-processing is same or greater than the solution itself, just so you can use an ill-fitting tool. Reminds me of that joke, "how do you measure height of a building with a voltmeter and a stopwatch? drop the voltmeter from the roof and time how long it takes to shatter on the ground." :P Sure, you can waste a voltmeter that way, or you can just grab a string.

Comment: @Amadan, yes on not-so-longish strings killing it (by causing the argument of `chr` to be negative). That should have occurred to me and, as you say, it's fixable (probably in an ugly way). I intended the second example to return `["123456", "23456", "3456", "456"]`. We may have interpreted the question differently. As I expect you surmised, I did this just to see how close I could get  to a regex solution. I thought it was a ham sandwich and a stopwatch.

Comment: There was no need to interpret: OP has a testcase, with input and expected output. Never heard about ham sandwich, but I guess the voltmeter version provides for a better garden path...

Answer (score 0):

```
string.each_char.with_object([]) do |e, acc|
  if acc.last && acc.last[-1] && e == acc.last[-1].succ
    acc.last << e
  else
    acc <<  e
  end
end.reject { |e| e.length < 3 }
```

---

this version might be easily adapted to work with any alphabet:

```
"11абвгнabcd$4567".codepoints.each_with_object([]) do |e, acc|
  e = e.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
  acc.last && acc.last[-1] && e == acc.last[-1].succ ? \
    acc.last << e : acc <<  e
end.reject { |e| e.length < 3 }
#⇒ [
#    [0] "абвг",
#    [1] "abcd",
#    [2] "4567"
# ]
```

Comment: @sagarpandya82 `codepoints` returns an array, not an enumerator.